# Python, Identify file in loop giving error: setting an array element with a squence

Tags: python, arrays, skip

I am using the code I wrote below to make different plots from 500 txt files. One of the files has some of the y values missing in the form below

```
1.000    2.005
2.000    2.006
3.000 
4.000
5.000    2.009
6.000    2.010
```

This gives me the error message: setting an array element with a sequence

I understand why I am getting the error message and fortunately, I know which file is causing it. After spending ages trying to work this out myself, what I would like to know is how I could get Python to skip the file when it detects the error and enter the loop again on the next file, whilst printing “error detected on ‘filename’”

Thanks

Here is my code:

```
from pylab import plot, ylim, xlim, show, xlabel, ylabel, grid, xscale, clf, savefig
from numpy import loadtxt
import glob


for filename in glob.glob('file-???.txt'):
    data = loadtxt(filename)
    x = data[:,0]
    y = data[:,1]
    plot(x,y, 'r-o', linestyle='-', markersize=0.05)
    xlim()
    ylim()
    xlabel("Energy (eV).")
    ylabel("count")
    grid(True)
    show()
    print(filename)
    savefig(filename + '.png')
    clf()
```

Comment: use a `try-except`?

Comment: maybe take a look at the `try` and `except`statements.

Comment: what about using the `try/except` statements?

Comment: Thanks guys that worked, damm I cant believe I how long I spent looking for such a simple answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from pylab import plot, ylim, xlim, show, xlabel, ylabel, grid, xscale, clf, savefig
from numpy import loadtxt
import glob


for filename in glob.glob('file-???.txt'):
    try:
      data = loadtxt(filename)
    except ValueError:
      continue
    x = data[:,0]
    y = data[:,1]
    plot(x,y, 'r-o', linestyle='-', markersize=0.05)
    xlim()
    ylim()
    xlabel("Energy (eV).")
    ylabel("count")
    grid(True)
    show()
    print(filename)
    savefig(filename + '.png')
    clf()
```